Why is VBA skipping over and not executing a line of code?
When I run the macro all of the lines execute except the code that is concatenating two columns together. When I go into debug mode it runs fine line by line and combines the correct columns in the correct destination, but it seems it doesn't have an end/doesn't stop at the defined variable, (which may be the issue?). Any idea why the code doesn't execute properly all at once, even though it works right individually?
'Worksheets("AR Detail").Activate

Dim DLrow As Range, cel As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim companycolumn As Range


Set DLrow = Range("O500").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -14)
Set companycolumn = Range("E3", DLrow.Offset(0, 4))


For Each cel In companycolumn
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "Order Form") > 0 Then
        cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = "MRETS - "
    Else
        cel.Offset(0, -1).Value = "MREC - "
    End If
Next cel

' imagine the next part of the code is in bold
For i = 3 To DLrow

   companycolumn.Cells(i - 2, 1).Value = Worksheets("AR Detail").Cells(i, 4).Value & Worksheets("AR Detail").Cells(i, 5).Value

Next i

I have no error handling in the macro, and I do not receive an error message when running the code as a whole, it just skips over it.

do you have On Error Resume Next in your code?  If so, remove it and see if it is erroring.

Qualify your Ranges with the sheet they are on so VBA does not assume you always want whatever sheet is active at the time. Ex: This is not qualified - Range("O500")

What's the value in DLrow ?  Is it a number less than 3?

@TimWilliams the value in dlrow is the last row of the data set, specifically in column A. So it should be greater than 3 because the last row is in the 400's.

@TimWilliams I just checked the variable, and it is returning the value of the cell in the last row which is "08/31/2023". Does it need to return the cell address to not skip over?

Also DLrows value is not the last row but the value in that cell itself.

Chang DLrow to Long and use: DLrow = Range("O500").End(xlUp).Row

@ScottCraner this got it to work, i will need to go back and clean it up!
